# How to use xmlHashScan function in libxml2 (c programming)

Tags: c, loops, hashtable, libxml2

Can anyone tell me **how to use the** **xmlHashScan** function and the **xmlHashScanner** fucntion in the library libxml2 ? 

I have read the libxml2 doc for these two functions but it doesn't cotain enough details. **Are these functions made to iterate a xmlHashTable ?**

I suprisingly found that no one ever has published code containing these functions on the Internet. Perhaps no one is using them ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686502/can-anyone-tell-me-in-detail-about-xmlhashscan-function-in-the-libxml2-library